# Angular - MEAN Stack - Trying to check user password in postman, issue with "bcrypt.compareSync"

Tags: angular, angularjs, mongodb, express, bcrypt

So I am trying to enable user authentication before adding jwt token and I am having an issue where the 'if' check is throwing the following error:

```
node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:265
        throw Error("Illegal arguments: "+(typeof s)+', '+(typeof hash));

Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string
at Object.bcrypt.compareSync
```

Here is my code for the user.js that is throwing the issue:

```
const { User } = require("../models/user");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

router.get(`/`, async (req, res) => {
  const userList = await User.find().select("-passwordHash");

  if (!userList) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false });
  }
  res.send(userList);
});

router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findById(req.params.id).select("-passwordHash");

  if (!user) {
    res
      .status(500)
      .json({ message: "The user with the given ID was not found." });
  }
  res.status(200).send(user);
});

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  let user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    color: req.body.color,
    passwordHash: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.passwordHash, 10),
    phone: req.body.phone,
    isAdmin: req.body.isAdmin,
    apartment: req.body.apartment,
    zip: req.body.zip,
    city: req.body.city,
    country: req.body.country,
  });
  user = await user.save();

  if (!user) return res.status(400).send("the User cannot be created!");

  res.send(user);
});

router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const userExist = await User.findById(req.params.id);
  let newPassword;
  if (req.body.password) {
    newPassword = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 10);
  } else {
    newPassword = userExist.passwordHash;
  }

  const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      name: req.body.name,
      email: req.body.email,
      color: req.body.color,
      passwordHash: newPassword,
      phone: req.body.phone,
      isAdmin: req.body.isAdmin,
      apartment: req.body.apartment,
      zip: req.body.zip,
      city: req.body.city,
      country: req.body.country,
    },
    { new: true }
  );

  if (!user) return res.status(400).send("the user cannot be created!");

  res.send(user);
});

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).send("The user is not found");
  }

  if (user && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.passwordHash)) {
    res.status(200).send("user Authenticated");
  } else {
    res.status(400).send("password is wrong");
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

So this piece of code in particular is the main issue I think

```
if (user && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.passwordHash))
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The message error says that the req body password argument is undefined

(req.body.password, user.passwordHash) => received (undefined, string)

you must do like this :

```
    if (user && req.body.password && 
      bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.passwordHash)) {
      // send response
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for everything!!!